# Possible to override site creation in Sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, mysite, sitedefs

We want to customize the "My Site" templates for different roles, say Students and Teachers. So basically we want to have one Site Def. for each and when they press "My Site" we want to create a new site using a different template depending on the role of the user (Student vs. Teacher). Does anybody know if this is even possible? Or any work-arounds that could work?

I know that it's possible to execute code during the process, I've seen lots of examples of this, but we want to do some stuff before that happens...

EDIT: Would it be possible to override the link to "my site" and then create a new site manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create a custom site definition for mysite. The way to go is described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/sharepoint/archive/2007/03/22/customizing-moss-2007-my-sites-within-the-enterprise.aspx) on the SharePoint team blog.
Then in the code to be executed, you can activate features based on the current user role.

That's the easiest (and supported) way I can think of.

Comment: Would it be possible to override the link to "my site" and then create a new site manually?

Comment: I guess it would be possible (not easily). However, you'll loose some functionnality related to mysite such as Office client and windows integration (you can let Windows remember your mysite).

Comment: We've decided to go with the Stabler/Stablee solution. :)